# log4j2 JSON configuration multiple appenders for root logger

Tags: java, json, log4j2

The log4j JSON docs give this as an example for configuration of the root logger:

`"root": { "level": "error", "AppenderRef": { "ref": "STDOUT" }}`

What do I do if I want to use 2 `AppenderRef`s, `STDOUT` and `FILEOUT`, for example?

This does not work (it only uses the last item in the array), and I've tried lots of others:

`"root": { "level": "error", "AppenderRef": [{ "ref": "STDOUT" }, {"ref": "FILEOUT"}]}`

I don't see an example here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#JSON

Comment: There's a typo in the config you posted: you con't close the `"ref": "FILEOUT"` object. That's not the problem, is it? Other than that, I would have thought your config should work.

Comment: It was a typo here, it's correct in the project - the config loads without error and only uses the last item in the `AppenderRef` array

Comment: I have to agree with @user31601 that what you have should work. I am able to use the exact syntax you posted with some basic appenders configured and it works. Since I can't recreate the issue based on the info in the question http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: as for examples you can explore log4j2 on github for example [json config with 2 appenders](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/dbd2d252a1b4139a9bd9eb213c89f28498db6dcf/log4j-core/src/test/resources/LOG4J2-1100/log4j2.json)